# How to get WebElement text with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Please see the following element:

```html
<div class="success"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
User 'MyUser' deleted successfully</div>
```

Find my element:

```python
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.success")
```

So after found this `div` and get the text using selenium with `getText` or `getAttribute("innerHTML")` the return:

```
×
User 'MyUser' deleted successfully
```

How can I get only the last line without this `x`?

Comment: Please post your element's lookup (e.g. `by.id("")`)

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: @davidhol :  could you try :`.getAttribute("textContent")` and reply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text you want is present in a text node and cannot be retrieved directly with Selenium since it only supports element nodes.

You could remove the beginning:

```java
String buttonText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.success > button")).getText();
String fullText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.success")).getText();
String text = fullText.substring(buttonText.length());
```

You could also extract the desired content from the `innerHTML` with a regular expression:

```java
String innerText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.success")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String text = innerText.replaceFirst(".+?</button>([^>]+).*", "$1").trim();
```

Or with a piece of JavaScript code:

```java
String text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return document.querySelector('div.success > button').nextSibling.textContent;");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("div.success")
element.getText();
```

shall help you get the text of the div

Answer (score 0):

Basically to get text in Selenium Java, we use .getText()

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='success']")
element.getText();
```

Make sure to print this.