# How do check for the content of a button in WebDriver using java?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code:

```
String ButtonHolder = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='block-success']//but‌​ton")).getAttribute(‌​"text");' 
System.out.println(ButtonHolder);
```

`HTML`

```
<button class="join-btn explore-flock">Explore Flock</button>
```

how do i check for the content "Explore Flock" from this code

Comment: Show how you tried. Also let us know what do you mean *to check for the content*

Comment: String ButtonHolder = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='block-success']//button")).getAttribute("text");
   
System.out.println(ButtonHolder);

i want check what is the button content on the site @Andersson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get WebElement text with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298400/how-to-get-webelement-text-with-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getText()` method or `getAttribute(‌​"textContent")` or `getAttribute(‌​"innerText")` instead of `getAttribute(‌​"text")` as `WebElement` has no such attribute as `text`

Answer (score 1):

You can get button text using

> getText

tag

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("")).getText());
```