# How do I retrieve the text which is kept under div class in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I wrote the xpath for an web element which is present under a div tag and it is not working. How do I write the xpath for the below html source.

**HTML Source code:**
[image]

Comment: share the code you have tried so far

Comment: Code trials and error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get WebElement text with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298400/how-to-get-webelement-text-with-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

Xpath is not the easiest and most flexible selector to understand and use. In addition, it is the slowest selenium selector.
Another disadvantage, you can not use compound classe.

The CSS selector is, I think, the best and the most readable since they are the same selectors used in CSS style sheets.

To recover your item, you can do :

```
WebElement element = this.webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.round.selleronboard h2"));
```

If you are not comfortable with the css selectors, [here is a simple documentation to understand](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Hoping that we were of help to you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **xpath** :

```
//h2[contains(text(),'Seller Management (Onboarding)')]
```

in case you would like to have css selector :

```
div.round.selleronboard h2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this xpath

```
//div[@class='round selleronborad']/h2]
```